# C++ Valgrind file descriptors

Tags: c++, valgrind

Can valgrind detect errors in code even if the code segment with errors is not hit during execution of testcases while the program is being started using valgrind?

What my question is that if valgrind can detect issues in code say related to mem leaks or unclosed file descriptors even if that portion of code with such errors is only executed in a particular scenario which is not being executed while running the program with valgrind.

Comment: Not totally familiar with valgrind but my immediate thought is 'no'. What you are talking about is called *static analysis* and there do exist tools to do it, but AFAIK, valgrind is not one of them.

Comment: There are other tools and other type of tools. Most probably you need static analysis tools: clang-analyzer, cppcheck, cpplint, .... .

Comment: You do measure the code coverage of your test suites? And everything is covered? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

No, `valgrind` is a 'runtime memory checker', it doesn't concern about any code which doesn't get run.

I suggest that even we don't know the mechanism,
we can do some tiny experiment to verify our hypothesize.

```
#include <malloc.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    if (argc > 1){
        printf("Let's leak some memory chunk.\n");
        char * a = malloc(100);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then check both of `valgrind ./a.out` and `valgrind ./a.out 1`, that's it.  :)